# Plot multiple lists on the same graph in r (scatter plot)

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I was trying to plot a graph that looks like the below figure based on the code under it:

[image: Figure]

```r
xAxisName <- c("ML", "MN")

car1 <- c(5,6)
names(car1) <- xAxisName
car2 <- c(5.5,6.2)
names(car2) <- xAxisName
car3 <- c(4.9, 5.4)
names(car3) <- xAxisName
```

The plot plots 2 car properties on the x axis and each property has 3 car values. But these are separate lists. How could this plot be plotted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the 'car' objects into a `list`, bind them with `bind_rows` and use `ggplot`, then pivot to 'long' format and use `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^car\\d+$')) %>%
     bind_rows(.id = 'car') %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -car) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, color = car)) +
        geom_point()+ 
     scale_y_continuous(expand = c(5, 6))
```

Comment: Is there a way to plot the values of cars side by side but not on the same line?

Comment: @moli sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: In the hand-drawn plot the values for "ML" for example are side by side. But with the answer the values are on a straight line. I was asking if there is any way to make ggplot look like the hand-drawn figure.

Comment: @moli I guess you meant to change the ytick interval

Comment: It could be, your answer solves the question but the plot would look prettier if the values of cars could be side by side like in the figure in the question

Comment: @moli current the y tick marks are automatically generated.  We can change those

Comment: How could we do that? If this is a separate question I can post another and tag you?

Comment: @moli I am checking on it.  It is just that we need to reduce the space between each tick mark

Comment: @moli can you try the updated `+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(5, 6))`

Comment: Thank you , I tried it but what I want is the values for "ML" to be side by side. So 5, 5.5 and 4.9 should not be on the same vertical line but next to each other. This should also be the same for "MN"

Comment: @moli can you please post as a new question as I not getting the expected as you wanted

Comment: I will tomorrow and tag this post

Comment: Posted a question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818802/plot-cross-validation-results-of-multiple-methods-in-one-plot-in-r

Comment: @moli I posted a solution in that link.  Hope it helps